# Webpack - Alias folder for use within installed package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I have some reusable React components published to NPM, that I am installing and using within my React application. Is it possible for me to set an alias in my React app, that can be used within these NPM components? For example, I want to allow the use of a folder `common`, which is within my React App, within the React components. So if I do this in my React components, it should work

```
import someVal from 'common';
```

I am bundling these React components with Webpack, and sending down the transpiled, bundled version for use within the React application. I tried setting the alias the regular way within the React app webpack config (by setting `resolve.alias`), but it does not work. Can this be done? Or am I approaching this incorrectly? Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Edit: So the React components from NPM are within my `node_modules` folder, and it is already bundled up via it's own Webpack config. I then run these components through my React application Webpack config as well (I'm whitelisting the folder), in the hopes that the new `common`  alias will be added there. But no luck. I keep getting a
`someVal is undefined` error.

My common file has the following: Ignore the logic for now (I'm only posting a part of the code)

```
import _myClass from '../components/MyClass';
const myClass = _myClass;  // Other things are done to it
export default myClass;
```

In my React components Webpack bundle file (after I fixed the default import statement)

```
/* harmony import */ var common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_25__ = __webpack_require__(/*! common */ "./src/common/index.js");
...
return common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_25__["default"].myFunction({
...
});
```

This still seems to be looking for `common` within the React components package, and not within the React app package that I am trying to use this in.

Comment: resolve.alias is the correct way of doing this. Maybe the mapping is wrong. Often you need to resolve the module path like so: `common: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/common')` since alias works with absolute paths and `__dirname` resolve the path of the config file. 
 What error do you get?

Comment: @tony Sorry for the delayed response. So the `resolve.alias` thing is not working, and I did use `path.resolve`. Added a little more explanation of my set up in case that clarifies the situation better. Thanks!

Comment: Usually if it is a case of not finding the module `common`, the error would be `unable to resolve module "common"`. It might just be case of `someVal` not being exported properly.

Comment: @tony updated the question with the content of `common`. It's a straightforward export of a class. Do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: You only have a default export in common. Therefore, you can only do import someVal from 'common and not import { someVal } from 'common';

Comment: @Bertrand - Yes, that was a stupid error on my part. But that did not solve the issue though. I fixed the import and I can see in the Webpack bundle file `/* harmony import */ var common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_25__ = __webpack_require__(/*! common */ "./src/common/index.js");` Still getting `someVal undefined` error.